# Missing Linq Methods in a PCL Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I have a working console app that has a complete set of functions to communicate with my remote mysql database (and they are all built using Linq expressions!).
After checking that the code has worked fine in the console, I created a PCL Cross-Platform App and installed the necessary packages (MySql, EF6 and others).

After moving the code to PCL, I saw that there were squiggles under some of my Linq codes like: (Where, FirstOrDefault, SingleOrDefaultAsync, etc) I mean, what? 
With a quick inspection on the intellisense i saw that I have now only basic Linq functions like Add, Remove, and a few others . 
***I DON'T want to rewrite my code again using context.users.SqlQuery("some Sql code here") !*** 
I read other posts and they wrote to check if the code has using System.Linq and I did! As I said, the database code is an exact copy of the code working in the console application.

When I hover over the squigling line , I get:

**Reference to type IListSource claims it is defined in System , but it could not be found!**

[See the LINQ code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3rOZ.jpg)

Comment: Projects that target cross-platform environments aren't compatible with some of the Windows namespaces - I know that portable class libraries that target iOS and Android cannot use System.Data, which rules out MySql and Linq.  You may need to tie into a web service to get the same functionality, or rewrite the code in a less Windows-dependent way...

Comment: SingleOrDefaultAsync is an extension method from EF6, which is not supported in Xamarin.